# My health bar fill image doesn't go off gradually

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a health bar for my project. I have tried a lot of different tutorials but none of them worked. My fill image goes full to empty every time. Is there something wrong with fill amount? Player's max hp is 200 currently and fill amount is 0-1, is it the couse of problem? thank you all.

I attached this script to a GameManager object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image FillImage;
    public int currentHealth1;
    public int maxHealth1;




    void Update()
    {
        FillImage.fillAmount = currentHealth1 / maxHealth1;
    }
}
```

and my player's max health and current health update the currenthealth1 and maxhealth1 on this script:

```
public PlayerHealthBar maxHealth1;
public PlayerHealthBar currentHealth1;


 public void Awake() { 

     currentHealth = maxHealth;
     currentHealth1.currentHealth1 = currentHealth;
     maxHealth1.maxHealth1 = maxHealth;

 }


void Update() {
currentHealth1.currentHealth1 = currentHealth;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poiyo.jpg)
this canvas is attached to the player and values changing without problem.
these are work well except the gradual fill, fill goes 0 instantly when damage taken.
[i think there is something wrong with my fill amount and the way i manupulate it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwWkG.jpg),[health values of player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5v9W.jpg)[values on the bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SB7i.jpg)
Note: I tried dividing values by maxhealth, and it still goes 0 or 1 not anyting in the middle
I also get this error:
DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
PlayerHealthBar.Update () (at Assets/PlayerHealthBar.cs:17)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is going to work, but you created 2 different PlayerHealthBars, one with each piece of information, so the PlayerHealthBar with the CurrentHealth1 variable being set by the player does not have a MaxHealth1 set by the player, but the other PlayerHealthBar has only the MaxHealth variable. So, you could do as this code:

```
public PlayerHealthBar healthBar


 public void Awake() { 

 currentHealth = maxHealth;
 healthBar.currentHealth1 = currentHealth;
 healthBar.maxHealth1 = maxHealth;

 }


 void Update() {
 healthBar.currentHealth1 = currentHealth;
 }
```

Comment: What I was trying to say is the fill amount is between 0 and 1. I want my player health values to be converted to 0 and 1. I tried to do it but nothing worked so far. the fill amount value is always 0 or 1.